# Can't decode JSON successfully from file

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a JSON file in my Xcode project. Let's use this as an example:

```json
{ "shifts": [ 
  {"name": "Mary", 
    "role": "Waiter"},
    {"name": "Larry", 
    "role": "Cook"} 
    ] 
 }
```

In my JSONManager.swift, I have something along the lines of this:

```swift
struct Shift: Codable {
    let role, name: String
    
    static let allShifts: [Shift] = Bundle.main.decode(file: "shifts.json")
}

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Could not find \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Could not load \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        return loadedData
    }
}
```

I keep hitting the error:

> fatalError("Could not decode (file) in the project")

and I'm wondering if it's because the JSON is not formatted correctly or why it can't decode the JSON from the JSON file.

Comment: You need a `struct` with a `shifts: [Shift]` property, which is then used as the decoable type

Comment: NEVER USE `try?` (with a question mark) unless you know how to debug. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`, but if you do a `fatalError` later that will crash, just use `try!` (with an exclamation mark).

Comment: @Larme The author of this function is Paul Hudson (the owner of very popular hackingwithswift.com). I already asked him not to spread this unhandy code but he didn't respond. Maybe he changes his mind if more people complain.

Comment: I'll add a complain too. While he does excellent work (I read it sometimes), I consider indeed as a flaw for beginners. For experienced ones, it's "fine" (since we "should" know how to debug), but for debutants, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at you JSON structure for a momement.

You have a element called `shifts`, which is any array of other elements, but your code seems to trying to load a structure which only contains the child element.

Instead, you need a outer `struct` which contains the child `struct`, for example...

```
struct Shift: Codable {
    let role, name: String
}

struct Shifts: Codable {
    let shifts: [Shift]
}
```

Then you'd use the parent `struct` as the initial source type when decoding the content...

```
extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Could not find \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Could not load \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loadedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        return loadedData
    }
}

let shifts: Shifts = Bundle.main.decode(file: "shifts.json")
```

I tested this in playgrounds and it worked fine.

There might be away to decode the structure without needing the "parent" `struct`, but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own mistake. I don't need the

```
{ "shifts": }
```

in my JSON