# Can't Decode JSON from file

Tags: json, swift

Struct File: LocationModel.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct NationalParkLocation: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : String
    let name: String
    let image : String
    let lat: Double
    let long: Double

}
```

JSON Data file: locations.json

```json
    [
  {
    "id" : "serengeti",
    "name" : "Serengeti National Park",
    "image" : "map-serengeti",
    "latitude" : -2.3333333,
    "longitude" : 34.8333333
  },
  {
    "id" : "kruger",
    "name" : "Kruger National Park",
    "image" : "map-kruger",
    "latitude" : -23.9883848,
    "longitude" : 31.5525515
  }
]
```

JSONManager.swift

```swift
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    func decode<T: Codable> (_ file: String) -> T {
            
            // 1. Locate the JSON file
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "data")
        else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle")
        }
        
        // 2. Create a property for data
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle")
        }
        
        // 3. Create a decoder
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        // 4. Create a property for the decoded data
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        
        // 5. Return the ready-to-use data
        return loaded
        
        
    }
}
```

MapView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    
 let locations: [NationalParkLocation] = Bundle.main.decode("locations.json")
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello! World")
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

I getting the error once on Preview:

> Failed to decode locations.json from bundle

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please compare the spelling of the keys with the struct members. They must match.

Comment: One major issue is that you are using `try?` and ignoring the real error so you don’t know exactly what is going wrong. Use `try` with a `do/catch` and print the real error

Comment: Thank you @vadian. I missed the keys matching of latitude and longitude

Comment: @JoakimDanielson See comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902295/cant-decode-json-successfully-from-file-swift Might worth a try to complain about it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationModel.swift` needs to be updated. The identifiers have to be identical. You have two options

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct NationalParkLocation: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : String
    let name: String
    let image : String
    let lat: Double //You can keep using "lat" and "long"
    let long: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case image
        case lat = "latitude" //You can specify the custom keys of latitude and longitude
        case long = "longitude"
    }
}
```

You can also do the much easier change here:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct NationalParkLocation: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : String
    let name: String
    let image : String
    let latitude: Double //Change it to latitude and longitude
    let longitude: Double
}
```